# dilemma with an opcode in a debugger

Tags: assembly

i got a line of code like this

```
push ff
push 0
push 0
push offset "this is a test"
push offset "Hello world!"       ; string in hex: 48656C6C6F20776F726C6421
push 0
CALL FUNCTION 1




MOV EDI,EDI
PUSH EBP
MOV EBP,ESP
PUSH ECX
PUSH ECX
PUSH ESI
PUSH EDI
XOR EDI,EDI
OR ESI,FFFFFFFF
MOV DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-4],EDI
MOV DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-8],EDI
CMP DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+0C],EDI
JE SHORT                         ; jump is taken
```

now going down the list of operations in the function

```
PUSH EBP
PUSH ECX 
PUSH ECX
PUSH ESI
PUSH EDI
XOR EDI,EDI                            ; will clear the edi register, it's zero now
OR ESI,FFFFFFFF                        ; esi will hold value ffffffff
MOV DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-4],EDI           ; copies edi to ecx
MOV DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-8],EDI           ; copies edi to 2nd ecx
```

now heres the part i dont get

```
CMP DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+0C],EDI
```

it's comparing edi which has a value of zero to ?

```
push offset "Hello world!" 48656C6C6F20776F726C6421
```

its comparing what? the JE command states jump is taken. whats not adding up here... i've looked further down in the code and i'm not seeing anything significant, why is it jumping if the string is being compared to 0

EDIT #1

here is the entire code again, from starting point, maybe you can find out what i'm doing wrong

start of program

```
00401000    6A 00           PUSH 0
00401002    68 00304000     PUSH OFFSET 00403000                  ; ASCII "this is a test"
00401007    68 17304000     PUSH OFFSET 00403017                  ; ASCII "Hello world!"
0040100C    6A 00           PUSH 0
0040100E    FF15 70204000   CALL DWORD PTR DS:[402070]
```

calls user32

```
750AFD1E  /$  8BFF          MOV EDI,EDI                 ; ID_X user32.MessageBoxA
750AFD20  |.  55            PUSH EBP
750AFD21  |.  8BEC          MOV EBP,ESP
750AFD23  |.  6A 00         PUSH 0                        ; /LanguageID = LANG_NEUTRAL
750AFD25  |.  FF75 14       PUSH DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+14]               ; |Type
750AFD28  |.  FF75 10       PUSH DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+10]               ; |Caption
750AFD2B  |.  FF75 0C       PUSH DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+0C]               ; |Text
750AFD2E  |.  FF75 08       PUSH DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+8]                ; |hOwner
750AFD31  |.  E8 A0FFFFFF   CALL MessageBoxExA                       ; \USER32.MessageBoxExA
750AFD36  |.  5D            POP EBP
750AFD37  \.  C2 1000       RETN 10
```

calls MessageBoxExA

```
750AFCD6  /$  8BFF          MOV EDI,EDI                     ; ID_X user32.MessageBoxExA
750AFCD8  |.  55            PUSH EBP
750AFCD9  |.  8BEC          MOV EBP,ESP
750AFCDB  |.  6A FF         PUSH -1                                  ; /Arg6 = -1
750AFCDD  |.  FF75 18       PUSH DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+18]               ; |Arg5
750AFCE0  |.  FF75 14       PUSH DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+14]               ; |Arg4
750AFCE3  |.  FF75 10       PUSH DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+10]               ; |Arg3
750AFCE6  |.  FF75 0C       PUSH DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+0C]               ; |Arg2
750AFCE9  |.  FF75 08       PUSH DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+8]                ; |Arg1
750AFCEC  |.  E8 37FEFFFF   CALL MessageBoxTimeoutA             
750AFCF1  |.  5D            POP EBP
750AFCF2  \.  C2 1400       RETN 14
```

calls MessageBoxTimeoutA

```
750AFB28  /$  8BFF          MOV EDI,EDI                        ; user32.MessageBoxTimeoutA
750AFB2A  |.  55            PUSH EBP
750AFB2B  |.  8BEC          MOV EBP,ESP
750AFB2D  |.  51            PUSH ECX
750AFB2E  |.  51            PUSH ECX
750AFB2F  |.  56            PUSH ESI
750AFB30  |.  57            PUSH EDI
750AFB31  |.  33FF          XOR EDI,EDI
750AFB33  |.  83CE FF       OR ESI,FFFFFFFF
750AFB36  |.  897D FC       MOV DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-4],EDI
750AFB39  |.  897D F8       MOV DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-8],EDI
750AFB3C  |.  397D 0C       CMP DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+0C],EDI
750AFB3F  |.- 74 19         JE SHORT 750AFB5A         <----- ollydbg states jump is taken
750AFB41  |.  6A 01         PUSH 1                                   ; /Arg6 = 1
750AFB43  |.  56            PUSH ESI                                 ; |Arg5
750AFB44  |.  8D45 FC       LEA EAX,[EBP-4]                          ; |
750AFB47  |.  50            PUSH EAX                                 ; |Arg4
750AFB48  |.  56            PUSH ESI                                 ; |Arg3
750AFB49  |.  FF75 0C       PUSH DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+0C]               ; |Arg2
750AFB4C  |.  57            PUSH EDI                                 ; |Arg1
750AFB4D  |.  E8 72D5FAFF   CALL MBToWCSEx                           ; \USER32.MBToWCSEx
750AFB52  |.  85C0          TEST EAX,EAX
750AFB54  |.- 75 04         JNZ SHORT 750AFB5A
750AFB56  |>  33C0          XOR EAX,EAX
750AFB58  |.- EB 6C         JMP SHORT 750AFBC6
750AFB5A  |>  397D 10       CMP DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+10],EDI    <----- jumps here
750AFB5D  |.- 74 27         JE SHORT 750AFB86     <----- jump is taken again
750AFB5F  |.  6A 01         PUSH 1                                   ; /Arg6 = 1
750AFB61  |.  56            PUSH ESI                                 ; |Arg5
750AFB62  |.  8D45 F8       LEA EAX,[EBP-8]                          ; |
750AFB65  |.  50            PUSH EAX                                 ; |Arg4
750AFB66  |.  56            PUSH ESI                                 ; |Arg3
750AFB67  |.  FF75 10       PUSH DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+10]               ; |Arg2
750AFB6A  |.  57            PUSH EDI                                 ; |Arg1
750AFB6B  |.  E8 54D5FAFF   CALL MBToWCSEx                           ; \USER32.MBToWCSEx
750AFB70  |.  85C0          TEST EAX,EAX
750AFB72  |.- 75 12         JNZ SHORT 750AFB86
750AFB74  |.  FF75 FC       PUSH DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-4]                ; /pMem
750AFB77  |.  57            PUSH EDI                                 ; |Flags
750AFB78  |.  FF35 0C010C75 PUSH DWORD PTR DS:[750C010C]             ; |Heap = 00350000
750AFB7E  |.  FF15 14000575 CALL DWORD PTR DS:[<&ntdll.RtlFreeHeap>] ; \NTDLL.RtlFreeHeap
750AFB84  |.- EB D0         JMP SHORT 750AFB56
750AFB86  |>  53            PUSH EBX      <--------- jumps here
750AFB87  |.  FF75 1C       PUSH DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+1C]               ; /Arg6
750AFB8A  |.  FF75 18       PUSH DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+18]               ; |Arg5
750AFB8D  |.  FF75 14       PUSH DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+14]               ; |Arg4
750AFB90  |.  FF75 F8       PUSH DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-8]                ; |Arg3
750AFB93  |.  FF75 FC       PUSH DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-4]                ; |Arg2
750AFB96  |.  FF75 08       PUSH DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+8]                ; |Arg1
750AFB99  |.  E8 2FFFFFFF   CALL MessageBoxTimeoutW                  
750AFB9E  |.  FF75 FC       PUSH DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-4]                ; /pMem
750AFBA1  |.  8B35 14000575 MOV ESI,DWORD PTR DS:[<&ntdll.RtlFreeHea ; |
750AFBA7  |.  57            PUSH EDI                                 ; |Flags
750AFBA8  |.  FF35 0C010C75 PUSH DWORD PTR DS:[750C010C]             ; |Heap = 00350000
750AFBAE  |.  8BD8          MOV EBX,EAX                              ; |
750AFBB0  |.  FFD6          CALL ESI                                 ; \NTDLL.RtlFreeHeap
750AFBB2  |.  397D F8       CMP DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-8],EDI
750AFBB5  |.- 74 0C         JE SHORT 750AFBC3
750AFBB7  |.  FF75 F8       PUSH DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-8]
750AFBBA  |.  57            PUSH EDI
750AFBBB  |.  FF35 0C010C75 PUSH DWORD PTR DS:[750C010C]
750AFBC1  |.  FFD6          CALL ESI
750AFBC3  |>  8BC3          MOV EAX,EBX
750AFBC5  |.  5B            POP EBX
750AFBC6  |>  5F            POP EDI
750AFBC7  |.  5E            POP ESI
750AFBC8  |.  C9            LEAVE
750AFBC9  \.  C2 1800       RETN 18
```

is it maybe somehow the debugger is throwing me off? say for example the first time it cmps it's not equal, so it doesnt jump, performs some operations, then attempts again, which result in the jump?

EDIT #2

I SOLVED THE PROBLEM, which was stupid, jump was NOT TAKEN after all, i ran the trace and it said command jump was not taken like i knew. but apparently i was just clicking on each command instead of pressing f7 to trace it :S that was silly... thanks for help though, i got more questions will post soon.

Comment: I agree that from your description it doesn't make sense. Does the stack actually look correct (is there a non-zero value at EBP+0C)?

Comment: well its a simple exe program and i've went through it with ollydbg and so far everything made sense, as it was calling and passing parameters but this cmp command i cant figure out and by the way it jumps to CMP DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+10],EDI which apparently points to the second string this is a test, after that it just gets ready to pass all the info into another function. This is inside a dll btw user32, the only thing at those locations are the offsets

Comment: just edited my question with entire code

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm mistaken, that comparison you're wondering about is comparing EDI (which is 0) with the the second argument, a string pointer. It's checking to see if the string is null.

Here's your MessageBoxExA:

```
750AFCD6  /$  8BFF          MOV EDI,EDI                     ; ID_X user32.MessageBoxExA
750AFCD8  |.  55            PUSH EBP
750AFCD9  |.  8BEC          MOV EBP,ESP
750AFCDB  |.  6A FF         PUSH -1                                  ; /Arg6 = -1
750AFCDD  |.  FF75 18       PUSH DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+18]               ; |Arg5
750AFCE0  |.  FF75 14       PUSH DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+14]               ; |Arg4
750AFCE3  |.  FF75 10       PUSH DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+10]               ; |Arg3
750AFCE6  |.  FF75 0C       PUSH DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+0C]               ; |Arg2
750AFCE9  |.  FF75 08       PUSH DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+8]                ; |Arg1
750AFCEC  |.  E8 37FEFFFF   CALL MessageBoxTimeoutA             
750AFCF1  |.  5D            POP EBP
750AFCF2  \.  C2 1400       RETN 14
```

And the start of MessageBoxTimeoutA:

```
750AFB28  /$  8BFF          MOV EDI,EDI                        ; user32.MessageBoxTimeoutA
750AFB2A  |.  55            PUSH EBP
750AFB2B  |.  8BEC          MOV EBP,ESP
750AFB2D  |.  51            PUSH ECX
750AFB2E  |.  51            PUSH ECX
750AFB2F  |.  56            PUSH ESI
750AFB30  |.  57            PUSH EDI
750AFB31  |.  33FF          XOR EDI,EDI
750AFB33  |.  83CE FF       OR ESI,FFFFFFFF
750AFB36  |.  897D FC       MOV DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-4],EDI
750AFB39  |.  897D F8       MOV DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-8],EDI
750AFB3C  |.  397D 0C       CMP DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+0C],EDI
750AFB3F  |.- 74 19         JE SHORT 750AFB5A         <----- ollydbg states jump is taken
```

On entry to `MessageBoxTimeoutA`, it pushes `EBP`, then sets `EBP=ESP`.

So what you have on the stack is:

```
[EBP+0C]    Arg2
[EBP+08]    Arg1
[EBP+04]    Return address
[EBP+00]    Previous EBP
```

At least, that's what it looks like. But you said that the jump is taken, which is pretty odd if you're not passing null as the `text` parameter.

Comment: yea i'm not getting it, i'm going to go down the entire section of the operation and see what happens if jump is not taken, even though olly tells me it is... maybe the first time it didnt take the jump but then does something and jump happens.... sounds like that maybe what is going on here

Comment: @davidwabb: I'd suggest pausing right before that `cmp` instruction and examining the stack. Or, better yet, single-stepping through it and examining the stack after every operation.